# Flask Install Error

Tags: python, unix, web, flask

Why am I getting this error below, I should be getting "Finished processing dependencies for Flask"

```
venv/bin/activate
(venv)david-mbp:~ David$ python setup.py develop
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(venv)davids-mbp:~ David$
```

Comment: Do a `ls` to see what files are in your present directory. `setup.py` is not in your present working directory.

Comment: how do I add it to my working dir?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you `cd`'d over to your virtual environment source to activate it and tried to run `setup.py` from there. Check that you're in the right folder.